# Error in x * scale : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to get rid of the exponential notation in the legend, but when I add `labels=scales::comma`, I get the error

```
Error in x * scale : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Code:

```
ggplot(nuts_df2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=cut(count, colbins, include.lowest = TRUE)), 
               color="white") +
  coord_fixed() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#000000','#000055',
                             '#000099','#0000FF'),
                    labels=scales::comma)
```

Comment: could we have  a [mcve] please? There is a `nuts2.df` in `cartography` but it doesn't seem to have the same variables in it: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cartography/versions/2.4.2/topics/nuts2.df  (You can probably make your example reproducible with something simple like the `mtcars` data set since there doesn't seem anything spatial/geographic-specific to the error you're getting ...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `cut(count, colbins, include.lowest = TRUE)`, you are making the fill aesthetic into a factor.

`scales::comma()` is designed to format numbers, not factors.

I think you want to override the labels of the fill categories in the `labels` argument of `cut()`, not in `scale_fill_manual()`.